# current path to 'from' when I import file

Tags: python, python-import, working-directory, python-os

In my computer with ubuntu 18.4 I'm running with pycharm this script

`file1_dir1.py`

```
from project.dir2 import file1_dir2
from project.dir1 import file1_dir1
```

but when I copy it to google vm with the same os I get

> No module named 'project'

or the same on windows..
how to find the current directory to 'from' and it's possible to do that dynamic for any os?

This is the directory tree for my project

```
project
            |
            |------- __init__.py
            |
            |------- dir1/
            |           |
            |           |----- __init__.py
            |           |----- file1_dir1.py
            |           |----- file2_dir1.py
            |
            |------- dir2/
            |           |
            |           |----- __init__.py
            |           |----- file1_dir2.py
            |           |----- file2_dir2.py
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you mean how to get the current directory that the python script is in?  ```os.getcwd()``` returns the current working directory

Comment: I mean to get to which path I need to writhe in
 'from dir1 import file1_dir1' or  'from project.dir1 import file1_dir1'
since I get the error I mentioed

Comment: Which of those directories, if any, are in `sys.path`?

Comment: Did you check `from dir1 import file1_dir1` or `from dir1.fire1_dir1 import *`?

Comment: yes I tried in few combination.. but with no successes for the vm..
In windows it's work like 'from dir1 import file1_dir1'